# Spring, Interceptors, some ExtJs and a HibernateException on console vs IntelliJ

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, interceptor

Weired world... let me try:

I have the follwing mavenized setup:
 - Springboot (1.5.5.RELEASE)
 - Hibernate (5.0.9.Final; I do know there is newer variants but I stick with what I have right now)
 - ExtJs (6.0.0)
 - IntelliJ (2017.3)

I do **partly** get running into an Hibernate Exception:

```
2018-11-20_15:04:58.007 [http-nio-8081-exec-7] [ERROR] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]:181 - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: 
Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread] with root cause  
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:697)
    ...
```

This does not happen on all threads! Partly the requests from ExtJs go through, Partly they don't. But would they not open a transaction on the webserver side?

I do have an Interceptor; well a web Interceptor implementing `org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor` 
Within the interceptor's `preHandle` method I do call a Service in order to check if a user is logged in and do some rights management handling.

The called `@Autowired` service fails. I thought the fact of accessing an `@Autowired` service method takes care of session/transaction handling.

Well, this was the scenario having my project manually created and run with a java-8 (java 8 sdk; not 9, not 10, not 11) command like from the console:

```
mvn clean package -DskipTests && java -jar target/MyBuild.jar application-local.properties
```

I just observed that the login consists of three request from browser to the backend. These three are all handled in separate threads by the backend.

When running the project within IntelliJ **it all works fine**. Ok, IntelliJ most likely does not *jar* the application and builds its own startup command.
But exactly that brings me out of rhythm due to the fact that we do process the code through a deployment / CI pipeline where we manually build the project.
And that is where it fails :-(

Amendment:
I changed everything to run with JPA instead of Hibernate (well it is still hibernate in the background). Just as 'M. Deinum' suggested.
Now, the problem still exists.
Two things I somewhat extracted.
In my Interceptor I do have some logging calls which ask the EntityManager for a hibernate-session (`entityManager.unwrap( Session.class )`).
This is the point where now.
So it seems that on the `preHandle(...)` of my interceptor there is **sometimes** no current session active. I am stating 'sometimes' since there are calls to the Interceptor when it works.

The exception comes as following now:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transactional EntityManager available
  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:272)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy117.unwrap(Unknown Source)
  at com.mypackage.dataaccess.DataAccessImpl.getCurrentSession(DataAccessImpl.java:89)
  at com.mypackage.dataaccess.DataAccessImpl.queryByHQL(DataAccessImpl.java:382)
```

Comment: Why are you using plain Hibernate instead of JPA? auto wiring and starting transactions have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: 1st: Using Hibernate instead of JPA is reasoned so far on old code setup. I agree not doing so. But I did not want to keep this refactoring as small as possible. I do agree. But would that help me right now? I already tried to use up2date hibernate libs + entitymanager instead if SessionFactory but did not succeed. - 2nd: I somewhat agree and disagree on the connection with \@Autowire and \@Transactional. Using an autowired service method which is annotated with \@Transactional does the session handling. The dependency injection and injected references do handle the tx management. Don't they?

Comment: The `@Transactional` is what manages the transactionality. Not the fact that you autowire something.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I ended up noting all Spring web controllers to have an **@Transactional** (where DB usage is given.)
That works.

From my understanding it does not matter where to put the *@Transactional* annotation as long as the method/owning Object is invoked through spring's *@Autowire* mechanism.
If I want something to run under the transactional behaviour I would annotated with it on the closest scope possible.
That's how I would decide where to put the *@Transactional*

At the end it does work but I am not satisfied with the solution.
If anyone could clarify the behaviour and/or my understanding let me welcomely know :-)